# Making Hangman in Processing

Tags: python, processing

I am currently trying to make the game Hangman using Python in Processing. I have the code to run the game, as well as code for some visuals. The problem is combining the code I've written so far. The game code is written in standard Python, while the visuals code is written in Processing. Can someone please help me combine the two and make a working Hangman game in Processing? Thank you in advance.

Code for game

```
import time
import random
name = input("What is your name? ")
print ("Hello, " + name, "Time to play hangman!")
print ('')
time.sleep(2)
print ("Start guessing...")
bank = ["ironman", "hulk", "captain america", "black widow", "thor", "hawkeye"]
r = (random.randint(0,5))
word = bank[r]
guesses = ''
turns = 10
while turns > 0:         
    failed = 0             
    for char in word:      
        if char in guesses:    
            print (char, )
        else:
            print ("_", )   
            failed += 1
    if failed == 0:
        print  ("You won")  
        break              
    print
    guess = input("guess a character:") 
    guesses += guess                    
    if guess not in word:  
        turns -= 1        
        print ("Wrong")   
        print ("You have", + turns, 'more guesses' )
        if turns == 0:           
            print ("You Lose")
```

Code for visuals

```
def setup():
    size(250,350)
    background(102,204,255)
    fill(17,214,11)
    rect(0,201,250,350)
   
def draw():
    strokeWeight(2)
    line(100,100,100,200)
    line(100,100,150,100)
    line(150,100,150,125)
    line(75,200,125,200)
    line(85,200,100,175)
    line(115,200,100,175)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put it all into Processing. It's much easier to add code to a visualization than to add a visualization to other code. There's also an issue with your Python code: think about what will happen if someone guesses multiple characters at once. What if they guess the entire alphabet?

As for actually making the game, you should try to put your Python code into Processing first. Make the game in Processing, then add the visualization. The current state of your game doesn't really work like a Processing sketch, so try getting yourself into the mindset of Processing (frame-by-frame). Make an animation before doing an interactive back-and-forth game like this.